# Syntax issue with mysql_result concerning number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

This is my current code:

```
<?php
//Account validation
session_start();
if(!(isset($_SESSION['login']))){
header("location:welcome.php");

}
else{
$userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
}

//connecting to mediadatabase
//server info
$server_username="root";
$server_password="";
$database="toob";
$server="127.0.0.1";

$db_handle=mysql_connect($server, $server_username, $server_password);
$db_found=mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

//Generating Media iD and checking against previous media ids already in use
$query= "SELECT max(media_id) FROM media WHERE id = '$userid'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to perform query");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($numrows > 0) {
$mediaid = mysql_result($result,0) or die("Can't retrieve cell");
$mediaid = $mediaid + 1;
} 
else{
print("No records exisiting");
$mediaid = 1;
}
print ($mediaid); 

?>
```

I am trying to find the largest number within the column "Media_id" for a specific user. Users are identified by their "id". If a result is found I want to create a variable based on the media_id value and call it $mediaid, following that I want to increment $mediaid by one. This variable will be used later in the programming. If there are no records for that user id however I want to set $mediaid to 1.

The issue is if no records exist for a user.  I have tried using the num rows function as you can see but it isn't working is this an issue with my syntax?? Any advice would be massively appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: what is your question exactly ... and please describe _The issue is if no records exist for a user._ how that cause error ?

Comment: what is the result if you `var_dump($numrows)` after `$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will return a row with `NULL` in the column `max(media_id)` in case of no rows found in your table 
So your `mysql_num_rows($result);` will always return 1;

You need to check the value for the max

```
//Generating Media iD and checking against previous media ids already in use
$query= "SELECT MAX(media_id) AS max_id FROM media WHERE id='$userid'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to perform query");

$mediaid = mysql_result($result,0) or die("Can't retrieve cell");

if($mediaid != null) {
   $mediaid = $mediaid + 1;
} else {
   print("No records exisiting");
   $mediaid = 1;
}
```

SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/360dc8/1/0

Comment: I replaced the if num rows with if(!($maxmediaid="NULL")){

Comment: One thing I have to delete the "or die can't retrieve cell" otherwise it quits to early

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
$mediaid = ($mediaid = mysql_result($result,0)) ? $mediaid++ : 1;
```

Explanation: if mediaid exists for that user then mysql_result() will return it and fill $mediaid variable (so if clause will be true and $mediaid will be set to $mediaid+1) otherwise mysql_result() will return false and $mediaid will be set to 1.